# Alert dialog is not showing in full screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, webview

My "no internet" alert dialog is not showing in full screen and also to mention that my button after i click not refreshing just disappear..what should i do to change it to open in full screen, i also tried with setContentView too, but it not worked..

This is my code..

Class file:

```
public class NetworkChangeListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(!Common.isConnectedToInternet(context)){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog,null);
            builder.setView(view);

            AppCompatButton btnRetry = view.findViewById(R.id.btnRetry);

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            btnRetry.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
                onReceive(context,intent);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f7f7f7"
    android:id="@+id/nointernet">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="212dp"
        android:layout_height="188dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_signal_wifi_off_24"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="253dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:text="Error!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="337dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:text="No internet connection"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="21dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"></TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRetry"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="Try again"
        android:layout_below="@id/text2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"></Button>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Main acitivity:

```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
       registerReceiver(networkChangeListener,intentFilter);
       super.onStart();
       recreate();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       unregisterReceiver(networkChangeListener);
       super.onStop();
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added this and it works fine..

```
<style>
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
<item name="backgroundColor">#f7f7f7</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">#f7f7f7</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

set minWidth and minHeight of 800dp/1000dp to RelativeLayout of your dialog layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f7f7f7"
    android:id="@+id/nointernet"
    minWidth="1000dp"
    minHeight="1000dp">
       // rest of the views.
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i solved that problem, but i cant reload webpage when internet is active..i want to reload the page on button click...i cant call "reload();" function in my class "NetworkChangeListener" because my webview is called in MainActivity ( protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) )..

Answer (score 0):

And code for button wich will reload webpage after i recreate activity:

```
btnRetry.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
  if (Common.isConnectedToInternet(context)) {
     dialog.dismiss();
     onReceive(context,intent);
     ((MainActivity)context).recreate();
  }
});
```